# How to use IF statement in asp.net using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to send an email once all these conditions are found to be true but my problem is that it is still sending an email out even if the condition is set to false.  For example, if either var3 or var4 or var5 is “NO” then I don’t want to send email out.  Here is the pseudo code for what I am checking and they all have to be true in order to send the email out:

```
If(var1 is not blank And var2 is not set to “YES” And (either var3 OR var4 OR var5 are not set to “NO”)
Then 
{
Send_Email();
}
```

here is my current code:

```
if var1 != ("&nbsp;") && var2!= "YES" && var3!= ("NO") || var4!= ("NO") || var5!= ("NO") ))
{
sendEmail();
}
```

Comment: you posted code that won't compile.  post your real code

Comment: The "current" code has syntax errors.

Comment: @Sam, asawyer, why do you presume the OP has managed to write compilable code?  I believe that is why he is here asking this question.

Comment: @KirkWoll because the OP said it still sends an email out with the incorrect conditions. So, it must have compiled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your conditions are pretty big, nothing stops you from writing multiple small methods to enhance readability.

Also, instead of checking for `!= "&nbsp"`, you should use `string.IsNullOrEmpty`.

```
private bool IsVar1Blank(string var1)
{
    return string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(var1);
}

private bool IsVar2SetToYes(string var2)
{
    return var2 == "YES";
}

private bool IsAnOtherVariableNotSetToNo(string var3, string var4, string var5)
{
    return var3 != ("NO") || var4 != ("NO") || var5 != ("NO");
}
```

And you get this result :

```
if (!IsVar1Blank(var1) && !IsVar2SetToYes(var2) && IsAnOtherVariableNotSetToNo(var3, var4, var5)
{
    sendEmail();
}
```

Also, to always be sure your code works, you should really look into writing [Unit Tests](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182532.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

try this

```
if (var1 != "&nbsp;" && var2!= "YES" && (var3!= "NO" || var4!= "NO" || var5!= "NO"))
{
   sendEmail();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use parentheses in your real code in the same way you do in the pseudo code:

```
if (var1 != ("&nbsp;") && var2!= "YES" && (var3!= ("NO") || var4!= ("NO") || var5!= ("NO")))
{
    sendEmail();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

do it like this

```
if( var1 != "&nbsp;" && var2!= "YES" && var3!= "NO" && var4!= "NO" && var5!= "NO" )
{
  sendEmail();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`if either var3 or var4 or var5 is “NO” then I don’t want to send email out.`

It looks like you should be using logical AND(`&&`) where you're using logical OR(`||`)

so the following will evaluate to true if **ANY** of `var3`, `var4`, or `var5` is not `"NO"`

```
var3!= ("NO") || var4!= ("NO") || var5!= ("NO")
```

change them all to `&&` so that you end up with

```
var1 != ("&nbsp;") && var2!= "YES" && var3!= ("NO") && var4!= ("NO") && var5!= ("NO")
```

---

---

Some other observations...

The opening paren on your if statement is missing, you should add it in.

```
if (var1 != ("&nbsp;") && var2!= "YES" && var3!= ("NO") || var4!= ("NO") || var5!= ("NO") ))
{
    sendEmail();
}
```

---

secondly, It's hard to tell what you want your condition to be.  with all the `||` and `&&`.  You should review the [C# order of operations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d.aspx) to make sure you're doing it right, and parenthesize if you're not.

as a note, `&&` gets evaluated before `||` does

---

finally, you should also create a breakpoint with the [debugger](http://www.dotnetperls.com/debugging) and make sure that your variables are what you think they should be.  Remember, the comparison you're doing is case sensitive.

Answer (score 2):

```
if(var1 != ("&nbsp;") && var2 ! = "YES" && (var3 != ("NO") || var4 != ("NO") || var5 != "NO")))
```

My guess is that your parenthesis are off.

Answer (score 2):

Right now your check will only work if ALL of the three vars are not `NO`.  This might be clearer:

```
if (var1 != ("&nbsp;") && 
    var2!= "YES" && 
    !(var3 == ("NO") || var4 == ("NO") || var5 == ("NO") )  // Any of these being "NO" will fail the `if` check
   )
{
   sendEmail();
}
```

Logically it's the same as:

```
if (var1 != ("&nbsp;") && 
    var2!= "YES" && 
    (var3 != ("NO") && var4 != ("NO") && var5 != ("NO") )
   )
```