# How to use Logical operator OR " || " in ASP .NET

Tags: asp.net, logical-operators

I've followed this question [How to use IF statement in asp.net using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18364871/how-to-use-if-statement-in-asp-net-using-c-sharp), but I really can make it out with my code.

```
if ((txtNome.Value == null) || (txtNome.Value == (""))
{

}
```

Here is the error

> The "||" operator cannot be applied a bool and string operands

I've tried all the possible solutions in the question above, but still not working. Some ideas?

Thank you

Comment: Assuming that `txtNome.Value` is a string, you shouldn't be using either of these. There is a `string.IsNullOrEmpty` method that returns a boolean value of true if the string is null or empty ("").

Comment: You're using `txtNome.Value = ("")` which should have `==` instead of `=` like `txtNome.Value == ("")`.

Comment: Read [ask] and elaborate on "still not working".

Comment: What does "still not working" mean? You have no code within your `if` block, so of course nothing happens if the value is null or an empty string... Please show a [mre].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Solution 1**

```
if ((txtNome.Value == null) || (txtNome.Value == ""))
    {

    }
```

**Solution 2** 
The same as above but without the extra round brackets.
These are unnecessary for single logical statements.

```
if (txtNome.Value == null || txtNome.Value == "")
{

}
```

**Solution 3**
Built in function for the above in C#

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtNome.Value))
{

}
```

Comment: Nice, a clear solution. If I would like to do it like the code above, would you update your question please? (It's just for learning)

Comment: Updated answer with additional info